# jQuery $.getScript does not work half of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, mapquest

I am using jQuery to load a script from Mapquest within the cordova onDeviceReady function. However, half the time the script does not load properly and the functions cannot be used.

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.s/mq-geocoding.js?key=sv99PLA3H8jGWSa1a097UKewBWrNWLWN",
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(){alert('hello')},
    async: false
  });
```

Is there anything that I can change to ensure that the script is always loaded properly? The script is always able to alert('hello'), but even then, the functions will not always work properly.

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.  (it won't even work here)

Comment: I tried that after reading another solution from a user from stackoverflow, however, the same problems were present even before the change

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that sometimes I will be able to call functions from the script but sometimes I will not

Comment: Have you tried to include a <script> tag and attach a callback to the onLoad event?

Comment: The script works 100% of the time if I load it normally with script tags instead of getScript, but the thing is I would like to load the script after everything else has loaded as there is a significant lag when loading the script, which results in the screen being blank for a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Are you calling the functions from the `success` function?  If you're calling them outside the `ajax` call, you're potentially calling them before the script is loaded.  That's probably why sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The function is called from a button click. Even when waiting for half a minute the function will still not work sometimes

Answer (score -1):

You can load the script dynamically without the `$.getScript` function as the following does:

```
function loadScript ( src, callback )
{
    var script = document.createElement ( 'script' );
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.onerror = function ( err )
    {
        throw new URIError('The script ' + err.target.src + ' is not accessible.');
    }

    if(callback && typeof callback == 'function')
        script.onload = callback;

    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
}
```

What it does is:

1. Creates a <script> element;
2. Tells the browser that it should be loaded asynchronously so it doesn't interrupts the rest of the resources while they load;
3. Uses the `onerror` and `onload` events to provide feedback on the script loading;
4. Appends the script to the <head> and sets the `src` making it actually load.

In your case, you'd use it like this:

```
loadScript ( "http://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.s/mq-geocoding.js?key=sv99PLA3H8jGWSa1a097UKewBWrNWLWN", function ( )
{
    alert(1);
} );
```

### Compatibility

Keep in mind that the async attribute does not works on all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async